# pywinauto how to click on a pane?

Tags: installation, automation, pywinauto

Dialog - 'sample'    (L585, T187, R1341, B716)
['Dialog', 'Sample', 'Sample']
child_window(title="Sivielliance Suite", control_type="Window")
|
| Pane - ''    (L588, T213, R1338, B713)
| ['Pane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
|    |
|    | Pane - ''    (L588, T213, R844, B673)
|    | ['Pane2']
|    |
|    | Pane - ''    (L588, T675, R1338, B713)
|    | ['Pane3']
|    |    |
|    |    | Pane - ''    (L588, T693, R1093, B694)
|    |    | ['Pane4']
|    |    |
|    |    | Pane - ''    (L1093, T681, R1333, B706)
|    |    | ['Pane5']
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L1255, T681, R1331, B706)
|    |    |    | ['Pane6']
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L1175, T681, R1251, B706)
|    |    |    | ['Pane7']
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | Pane - ''    (L1095, T681, R1171, B706)
|    |    |    | ['Pane8']
|    |
|    | Pane - ''    (L588, T673, R1338, B675)
|    | ['Pane9']
|    |    |
|    |    | Pane - ''    (L588, T673, R1338, B675)
|    |    | ['Pane10']
|    |
|    | Pane - ''    (L844, T271, R1338, B673)
|    | ['Pane11']
|    |    |
|    |    | Pane - ''    (L844, T271, R1338, B673)
|    |    | ['Pane12']
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    | Image - ''    (L852, T286, R1330, B305)
|    |    |    | ['Image', 'Image0', 'Image1']
|    |
|    | Pane - ''    (L844, T213, R1338, B271)
|    | ['Pane13']
|    |    |
|    |    | Image - ''    (L854, T231, R1043, B252)
|    |    | ['Image2']
|
| TitleBar - ''    (L604, T190, R1338, B213)
| ['TitleBar']
|    |
|    | Menu - 'System'    (L593, T195, R615, B217)
|    | ['System', 'Menu', 'SystemMenu', 'System0', 'System1']
|    | child_window(title="System", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
|    |    |
|    |    | MenuItem - 'System'    (L593, T195, R615, B217)
|    |    | ['System2', 'MenuItem', 'SystemMenuItem']
|    |    | child_window(title="System", control_type="MenuItem")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Minimize'    (L1199, T188, R1246, B213)
|    | ['Button', 'MinimizeButton', 'Minimize', 'Button0', 'Button1']
|    | child_window(title="Minimize", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Maximize'    (L1246, T188, R1292, B213)
|    | ['Button2', 'MaximizeButton', 'Maximize']
|    | child_window(title="Maximize", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Close'    (L1292, T188, R1339, B213)
|    | ['CloseButton', 'Button3', 'Close']
|    | child_window(title="Close", control_type="Button")

I am unable to click on any of the child panes. Is there any solution for this?

[Control identifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q8Ij.png)

```
app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=2).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=2).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).app.dlg.child_window(control_type="Pane",found_index=0).click_input()
```

Comment: Did you try autoit only commands? ControlClick and so on?

Comment: I tried click_input() , It works for few panes but I am unable to identify few panes.

Comment: Autoit Window Info doesn‘t provide any useable information about the tabs?

Comment: Everything is showing as Pane and I am unable to reach few of the nested panes say Pane 19 as shown in the attached image. I am unable to figure out what's the difference between depth, ctrl_index and found_index @Xenobiologist